# Simplify multiple nested loop

Tags: python

for a math riddle i wrote that python program to bruteforce the solutions. ABCD * 3 = EFGHI with each ABCDEFGHI different from each other (and 3 of course).

```
#   Game looking like : ****
#                       X   3
#                     = *****
# with each * diferent from others and is in interval [0-9] except 3 (as the last * being imposed)


import time
t1 = time.time()
occurence = 0
for a in range(0,10):
    if a == 3 : continue    
    tn = time.time()
    delta = tn - t1
    # each number should be different so a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i are
    # each one and unique number in [0-9] excluding 3    
    for b in range(0,10):
        if a == b or b == 3 : continue
        
        for c in range(0,10):
            if a == c or b ==c or c == 3 : continue
            for d in range(0,10):
                if d==a or d==b or d==c or d == 3 : continue
                for e in range(0,10):
                    if e==a or e==b or e==c or e==d or e == 3: continue
                    for f in range(0,10):
                        if f ==a or f==b or f==c or f==d or f==e or f == 3: continue
                        for g in range(0,10):
                            if g ==a or g==b or g==c or g==d or g==e or g==f or g == 3: continue
                            for h in range(0,10):
                                if h ==a or h==b or h==c or h==d or h==e or h==f or h==g or h == 3: continue
                                for i in range(0,10):
                                    if i == a or i==b or i==c or i==d or i==e or i==f or i==g or i==h  or i == 3: continue
                                    first = 1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d
                                    result = 10000*e + 1000*f + 100*g + 10*h + i
                                    if (first *3 == result):
                                        #on a un gagnant
                                        occurence +=1
                                        print(first, "* 3 =", result)
                                        t2 = time.time()
print(occurence, "positiv results")
print(t2-t1, "seconds")
```

I'm pretty sure this code could have been way lighter using list and that's why i post today.

Comment: As your code works but you're asking for help improving it, it might be a better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: Would be easier to just iterate over all permutations of the digits 0-9 without 3 and then split them to ABCD and EFGHI

Comment: What exactly is the code ultimately doing...?

Comment: You definitely want to use an array here instead of different variables

Comment: `for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i in itertools.permutations((0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9)):` could replace all the for loops.

Comment: Note that the last loop on `i` is completely unnecessary as it already has only one option anyway. You could do `i = sum(range(10)) - 3 - sum([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h])`

Answer (score 6):

Besides using `permutations`, you do not need to test all the permutations for all the nine digits at all. Instead, get all `combinations` for the first four digits, then the `permutations` of those (or, as pointed out in comments, use `permutations` with optional `r` parameter), and check if that together with 3x that number is a permutation of all the allowed digits.

```
from itertools import permutations

digits = list("012456789")
for perm in permutations(digits, r=4):
    first = int(''.join(perm))
    second = first * 3
    if sorted(f"{first}{second}") == digits:
        print(f"{first} * 3 = {second}")
```

(Edit: Using `permutations` with `r=4` and `sorted` instead of `set` to check for duplicate digits, although that should not be an issue here.)

For me, this reduces the running time from ~1.06 seconds (your original code) or 0.21 seconds (using `permutations`, but all) down to 0.007 seconds.

Comment: Nice! didn't think the difference will be so big, and I wasn't thinking that the set check is that simple... But why do you do the permutation of the combinations? I couldn't figure that out. Wouldn't work with a simple `for perm in permutations("012456789", 4)`?

Comment: BTW, on closer inspection this is not entirely correct. Converting to `set`, some digits could be repeated. This is not a problem here, as 4 digits x3 can not produce a 6 digit number, but to be correct you could also compare the combined `sorted` digits.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for pointing this out, I completely forgot `permutations` had that parameter!

Comment: Did you check the timing again? I would assume that the remove of redundant combinations will improve even more!

Comment: @Tomerikoo There were no redundant combinations, since all the digits were unique in the first place. It's just a lot cleaner. The inner loop (before the `if`) is executed 3024 times either way (as opposed to 362880 times with all permutations).

Answer (score 2):

Create all [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) of the 9 numbers, split them to your two operands and check the condition:

```py
from itertools import permutations

digits = "012456789"

for perm in permutations(digits):
    abcd = int(''.join(perm[:4]))
    efghi = int(''.join(perm[4:]))
    if abcd * 3 == efghi:
        print(abcd, efghi)
```